# Tkinter windows popping up and not able to close them

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a tkinter GUI python code that creates a gui interface to my code, in the code later snack sound toolkit is used (which also uses Tk and creates an instance using root = Tk()). As, mainloop of the previously GUI application is already running to everytime snack function is called a new empty default tk window pops up. As this happens quite a lot, there are hundreds of empty tk windows on screen when this code executes. I have tried to close them using numerous methods root.destroy,root.withdraw, WM_DELETE_WINDOW etc. but to no solution.
Is there any way this can be done in tkinter?

```
import tkSnack
import thread

import Tkinter as tk

class my_gui(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Get", command=self.on_button)
        self.button.grid(row=8)

    def on_button(self):

        thread1 = thread.start_new_thread(run, (PATH_TO_WAVE_FILE,))

def run(path):

    for k in range(10):

        PITCH_VALUES = snack_work(path)
        print PITCH_VALUES

def snack_work(INPUT_WAVE_FILE):
    # initializing the snack tool
    root = tk.Tk()
    tkSnack.initializeSnack(root)
    # root.withdraw()
    mysound = tkSnack.Sound()

# processing original wave file
    mysound.read(INPUT_WAVE_FILE)

    PITCH_VALUES = mysound.pitch()
    return PITCH_VALUES

app = my_gui()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I guarantee you that you're using that toolkit the wrong way. Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 added a small code which shows how i am doing and also reproduces the issue

Comment: The Snack toolkit doesn't initiate `Tk()`, you do, in the first line of `snack_work`. Snack needs an instance of Tk to run, but your `my_gui` class already inits Tk. I don't use Snack myself, but I'm guessing there's no need to do `root=tk.Tk()` in `snack_work`. Either way, calling more than one instance of Tk is always a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `run()` and `snack_work()` into instance methods of your `app` object, so that they can easily access that object's attributes. To work with a more minimal MCVE that doesn't rely on external libraries or files, I tested the following with simple `print()` (I'm on Python 3) and `after()` calls rather than `snack` stuff, as all I wanted to check was that the other functions could access a `tkinter` object.

```
import tkSnack
import thread
import Tkinter as tk

class my_gui(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Get", command=self.on_button)
        self.button.grid(row=8)

    def on_button(self):
        thread1=thread.start_new_thread(self.run,(PATH_TO_WAVE_FILE,))

    def run(self, path):
        for k in range(10):
            PITCH_VALUES = self.snack_work(path)
            print PITCH_VALUES

    def snack_work(self, INPUT_WAVE_FILE):
        ## initializing the snack tool
        tkSnack.initializeSnack(self) # use self instead of the separate root object
        # self.withdraw()
        mysound=tkSnack.Sound()

        ## processing original wave file
        mysound.read(INPUT_WAVE_FILE)

        PITCH_VALUES= mysound.pitch()
        return PITCH_VALUES

app = my_gui()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks @TigerhawkT3 ... it works ... now comes the big task of integrating this change to the big code :D